# Get reference to jQuery from jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I'm writing some tests for an ASP.Net page with `UpdatePanel` postbacks.  I run the tests from one page (the outer page), and load the page being tested into an `iFrame`.  Then the outer page gets a reference to the tested page's jQuery object on load.

I have a hunch that after an async postback, something funky is happening and the test page's jQuery object is being overwritten, but my outer page's reference to it is not being updated (or vice versa--not sure yet).

I have a reference to a jQuery-wrapped DOM element in the test page.  How do I get a reference to the jQuery object used to wrap it so that I can compare it to the jQuery reference my outer page knows about?

#### EDIT

What I mean is this:

```
var x = $(foo);
if (someFunc(x) == $) {
    // success!
}
```

I need to define `someFunc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery object's `constructor` property points back to `jQuery`:

```
> jQuery().constructor === jQuery
true
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I mean.  Maybe I'm not understanding.  I updated my question with an example.

Comment: `someFunc` would be `return x.constructor;`.